# Hosting an application-hosted media

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks

Team,

As mentioned in the doc(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/requirements-considerations-application-hosted-media-bots), the bot can be only deployed on service fabric and VM.

Observation

```
 1. We can only host on service fabric cluster or VM apart from Classic Cloud.
```

Questions.

```
 1. What are the dependencies so that it only works on above mentioned services?

 2. If not, can we use Azure AppService(WebApps) or AppService Instance to host?
```

Comment: We are checking this internally and get back you soon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can use Azure App Service to host a bot. You can get the detailed overview in this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/abs-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#:%7E:text=%20Create%20a%20new%20bot%20service%20%201,specified%20in%20the%20table%20below%20the...%20More).
Secondly, if you are using Azure service fabric or VM, the dependencies the already explained in this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/abs-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#:%7E:text=%20Create%20a%20new%20bot%20service%20%201,specified%20in%20the%20table%20below%20the...%20More)